# Java non-generic method hiding generic method with intersection types

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, jls, method-hiding

If three public interfaces are defined as:

```
public interface One{}
public interface Two{}
public interface Three{}
```

And another class, Super, is defined as:

```
public class Super {
    public static <E extends One & Two & Three> void hmm(E item) {}
}
```

Why does the following subclass of Super give a compile error?

```
public class Subber extends Super{
    public static void hmm(One item) {}
}
```

I would expect the above method to simply hide the method from Super, but that does not seem to be the case.

The JLS (8.4.8.2) says:

> If a class C declares or inherits a static method m, then m is said to hide any method m', where the signature of m is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m', in the superclasses and superinterfaces of C that would otherwise be accessible (§6.6) to code in C.

where a subsignature is defined in 8.4.2 as:

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.

> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either: m2 has the same signature as m1, or the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.

The erasure of a type variable is the erasure of its leftmost bound, as per JLS 4.6, so:
As far as I understand, Subber's hmm method is the same as the erasure of Super's hmm method, and would therefore be a subsignature of Super's hmm, thus meaning it would hide Super's hmm. However, the error message I get (from eclipse), which doesn't seem to make sense given the above is: "The method hmm(One) of type Subber has the same erasure as hmm(E) of type Super but does not hide it." What am I missing?

Edit: The precise error message, where the main method simply contains `Subber.hmm(null);` is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Name clash: The method hmm(One) of type Subber has the same erasure as hmm(E) of type Super but does not hide it

    at base/testpack4.Subber.hmm(Subber.java:4)
    at base/testpack4.Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

**Could someone explain why Subber's method does not compile, citing a credible source (preferably the JLS)?**

Comment: can you include the compiler error message?

Comment: added, thanks @matt b

Comment: What is your Java version? I can't reproduce it on Java 14.

Comment: Hmm... I'm using Java 14 as well. I just tried compiling it from the command line (javac and java version 14.0.1) and it compiles and runs correctly, yet when using eclipse (Compiler compliance level 14, jdk 14.0.1, using javaw.exe) I get the compile error above.  Maybe this is a difference between javaw.exe and java.exe? I honestly have no idea.

Comment: It could be a bug in the eclipse java compiler

Comment: Just did a fresh install of IntelliJ, and ran it again using jdk-14.0.1 and java.exe (not javaw), but this time it compiled and worked correctly. I guess it is a bug with eclipse or javaw. Damn, that sucks, I guess I'll have to go figure that out now...

Comment: java.exe and javaw.exe are just different launchers for the same JVM (only the runtime). The different java compilers are javac.exe and ecj (eclipse compiler for java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> „*...Could someone explain why Subber's method does not compile...*“

I [*implemented the code you listed*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_296189); *verbatim*. And my *`Main.main(String[])`* compiles fine with a call to *`Subber.hmm(null)`* and *`Subber.hmm(One)`*.

The only thing different I did was introduce a new *`Four`* interface that meets the requirements of the type parameter section of *`<E extends One & Two & Three> void Super.hmm(E)`*.

Then I passed an instance of *`Four`* into *`Subber.hmm(One)`* to confirm that *`Super.hmm(E)`* wasn't being called; proving it is actually hidden.

> „*...citing a credible source (preferably the JLS)?...*“

[*That implementation*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_296189) behaves exactly as the JLS spec that you cited describes.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the reason why it did not compile for me was because I was using the eclipse compiler, which does not conform perfectly to the JLS in this regard. I went ahead and marked this answer as correct.

Comment: Cool! Thanks @SamHooper. What version of Eclipse and which JDK were you running in it when you got the compilation error?

Comment: I was using jdk 14.0.1, with eclipse version 2020-06 (4.16.0).

Answer (score -2):

The type for E is still undefined, you can go and parameterize it via setting the E generic for the Super class and define it in the Subber class:

```
public class Super<E> {
    public static <E extends One & Two & Three> void hmm(E item) {}
}

public class Subber extends Super<One> {
    public static void hmm(One item) {}
}
```

Comment: It's not `Super<E>`, it's just `Super`. The method is parameterized, not the class.

Comment: Yes, I understand, that's the issue. You can create a generic method in a non generic class, but that method is not would not match the generics to "override" the signature, it will only clash, because the generic is at method level and not hierarchy level.

Comment: If you feel like you know what the issue is, you should cite the correct JLS location and be a lot more elaborate in your answer. As is, this answer is just showing *different* code than what is in the question.